# How to update variables with jQuery UI in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to create several jQuery UI sliders in a loop. this is my code:

JavaScript:

```
var teile = new Array();    
teile[0] = 100;
teile[1] = 200;
teile[2] = 300;

$(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $('#slider' + [i]).slider({
            value: teile[i],
            min: 0, max: 600,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                teile[i] = ui.value;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slider0"></div>
<div id="slider1"></div>
<div id="slider2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider0{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 600px;
}
#slider1{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 600px;
}
#slider2{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 600px;
}
```

It works so far, but the values of the variables don't seem to update when using the slider. If i don't use a loop it works this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, but i think the problem is in scope.

```
$(function() {
  for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    (function(index) {
      $('#slider'+[index]).slider({
        value: teile[index],
        min: 0, max: 600,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          teile[index] = ui.value;
        }
      })
    })(i);
  }
});
```

Comment: That would haven taken me a loooong time to figure out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. @1Blerk the key point here is, JavaScript is an asynchronous language.

Answer (score 1):

You need a closure:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $('#slider' + [i]).slider({
        value: teile[i],
        min: 0,
        max: 600,
        slide: (function (index) {
            return function (event, ui) {
                teile[index] = ui.value;
            }
        })(i)
    })
}
```